# Mysql: Using Limit with Con

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I've got this this query which gives me all the ratings for a particular country:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country, GROUP_CONCAT(rating ORDER BY rating DESC ) AS Ranking
FROM final
group by Country
ORDER BY Country;
```

Table is something like this:

```
"Country"   "Rating"    "Title" 
" zimbabwe" "0" "Biology Study Guide" 
" zimbabwe" "0" "Impact: A Guide to Business Communication (Esl English 2nd Language Series)" 
" zimbabwe" "0" "Wayside School Gets a Little Stranger (Wayside School)" 
" ysa"  "5" "Side effects" 
" ysa"  "9" "The Last Precinct" 
" ysa"  "0" "The Horse Whisperer" 
" x"    "0" "The Evi 
" yugoslavia"   "0" "Wild Animus" 
" yugoslavia"   "8" "Complete Works of William Shakespeare (Wordsworth Royals Series)" 
" yugoslavia"   "3" "Wild Animus"
```

I've run into two problems. Im trying to limit the ratings to 10 per country. I added `LIMIT 10` after `DESC` and i get a syntax error.

Second issue is that in DESC order, 10 is lower than 9 because it starts with 1. How can i deal with that?

Comment: Show us the `final` table.

Comment: Its something like this:

"Country" "Rating" "Title"
" zimbabwe" "0" "Biology Study Guide"

" zimbabwe" "0" "Impact: A Guide to Business Communication (Esl English 2nd Language Series)"

" zimbabwe" "0" "Wayside School Gets a Little Stranger (Wayside School)"

" ysa" "5" "Side effects"

" ysa" "9" "The Last Precinct"
" ysa" "0" "The Horse Whisperer"
" x" "0" "The Evi
" yugoslavia" "0" "Wild Animus"
" yugoslavia" "8" "Complete Works of William Shakespeare (Wordsworth Royals Series)"
" yugoslavia" "3" "Wild Animus"

Comment: Please update your question with this data.

Answer (score 2):

In order to limit the `GROUP_CONCAT()` you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to cut needed elements. To order strings as numbers, you can use `CAST()` for that. So you query should look like as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Country,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(rating ORDER BY CAST(rating AS UNSIGNED) DESC), ',', 10
    ) AS Ranking
FROM
    final
GROUP BY
    Country
ORDER BY
    Country;
```

Comment: Getting an Incorrect parameter count to native call at substring index error.

Comment: Yes, there was syntax error with brackets, now is OK.

Comment: Awesome its working. I understand the CAST() but a bit confused on the substring index for the whole statement. Will have to read more about that. Thanks mitkosoft.